# How to redirect login and register pages

Tags: pages, login, user-registration

I have a WordPress site which has the built-in login form with the url `http://domain.com/wp-login.php` and register page `http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=register`

I want to display these forms on a page I created from the backend.

login

```
http://domain.com/profile/login
```

register

```
http://domain.com/profile/register
```

Is it possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/wp-login.php  http://domain.com/profile/login
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=register   http://domain.com/profile/register
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: are there another way out using `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Theme My Login plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/